# Angular routing

Tags: angularjs

Все доброго времени суток, нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.
Есть get запрос и соответсвенно в url:
http://domain/dashboard?region=USA&sellers=10.
Использую routeProvider.
Как правильно прописать .when('/dashboard', {...}), чтоб роутинг мог понимать что я нахожусь на этой странице?

Comment: в принципе ты уже прописал.

Answer (score 0):

Да, собственно вы уже пол дела сделали, в результате должно выглядеть так:

```
$routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "путь к странице"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$routeProvider.when('/dashboard?region&sellers', {
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
});
```

А внутри контроллера можете получить параметры из ура с помощью $routeParams